# How to be DRY when need to have same conditional operator in every setter?

Tags: java, dry, setter

So I have a class with fields that cannot have certain values. I put a condition in every setter, but I'm not sure it's a good idea, since this is the same "if" with the same conditions in every setter. Here the example of setter (java):

```
public void setBuildingNumber(String buildingNumber) {
    if (buildingNumber.equals("-1") || buildingNumber.equals("0") || buildingNumber.equals("N/A")) {
        this.buildingNumber = null;
    } else {
        this.buildingNumber = buildingNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that condition really is the same check i.e. 0, -1, N/A on ever setter you might consider a tiny private function that returns a boolean. I'd weigh that option against the number of setters you have though to make sure you don't overcomplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a validation method that returns the default value if it fails, ie

```
private static String getValidValue(String candidate) {
    return (candidate.equals("-1") || candidate.equals("0") || candidate.equals("N/A") ? null : candidate;
}
```

which will make your setters

```
public void setBuildingNumber(String buildnumber) {
    this.buildnumber = getValidValue(buildnumber);
}
```

So far, this is pretty much the same as the other answer.

If the valid values vary, you can create a validation factory method.

```
private static <T> Function<T,T> createValidator(Predicate<T> valid, T defValue) {
    return s -> valid.test(s) ? s : defValue;
}
```

and then put together your validators like this

```
static Function<String, String> getValidBuildingNumber = createValidator(
    s -> !"0".equals(s) && !"1".equals(s) && !"N/A".equals(s), null);
```

to be used in your setter like this:

```
public void setBuildingNumber(String buildingnumber) {
    this.buildingnumber = getValidBuildingNumber.apply(buildingnumber);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Write a static method for that logic:

```
public static boolean isEmpty (String input) {
    return input == null || input.equals("-1") || input.equals("0") || input.equals("N/A");
}
```

And use it in every setter:

```
public void setBuildingNumber(String buildingNumber) {
    this.buildingNumber = isEmpty(buildingNumber) ? null : buildingNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

well, since they have already given solutions, I just want to remind you that you'd better replace

```
buildingNumber.equals("-1")
```

with

```
"-1".equals(buildingNumber)
```

just in case it is a null

Comment: Thank you. And I already put lots of "if"s to check for null. I guess I'll do some refactoring.